# fsck problem: can't write commands in the built-in shell in boot

Tags: 18.04, fsck

I had a problem with `fsck` on Ubuntu that when I write `fsck /dev/sda4` it writes symbols instead of command:

[image: <code>error image</code>]

Comment: Have you any language keyboard installed in addition to English? Tryed to switch language?

Comment: yes i have arabic but how can i switch

Comment: @ChamsAgouni Run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`

Comment: Try Super+Space

Comment: Try to change language, if fail with it - you can run fsck from live cd/usb

Comment: okay i will use usb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**At the initramfs prompt, type:**

`fsck -f /dev/sda4`

Repeat this command if there are errors.

Or...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda4`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

This may not fix the problem. We can't see the complete error messages in the image that you posted. It looks like you have some badblock(s) on your HDD.

You may need to boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, run the `Disks` application, go to the hamburger icon, choose `SMART Data & Tests`. Review the data, looking for any items with the word (relocated or pending) `sector`. Report back. Also run the tests.

**If you wish to test for bad block(s)...**

`sudo e2fsck -fck /dev/sda4` # read-only test

or

`sudo e2fsck -fcck /dev/sda4` # non-destructive read/write test (**recommended**)

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fcck parameter...

```
   -f     Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c     This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program  to  do  a
          read-only  scan  of  the device in order to find any bad blocks.
          If any bad blocks are found, they are added  to  the  bad  block
          inode  to  prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
          tory.  If this option is specified twice,  then  the  bad  block
          scan will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k     When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
          bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks  found  by
          running  badblocks(8)  will  be added to the existing bad blocks
          list.
```

Comment: but i cant type in the prompt

Comment: it write some wiered symbols

Comment: @ChamsAgouni even if you boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB?

Comment: no i dont have this right now

Comment: @ChamsAgouni you won't be able to fix/test your computer without a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.

Comment: i fixed it with alt+ char number 

Comment: @ChamsAgouni  Were you able to complete the `fsck` and the `e2fsck` commands, and if so, is your computer working again? If so, please remember to accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks!